# Jtable doesn't refresh/update data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, defaulttablemodel

I have a problem with `JTable`/`JScrollPane`. My data table is not refreshing/updating. I am using `DefultTableModel` and according to the code everything is fine and I don't have any errors. Also I have a table with paging and that's why I am using action listeners and buttons "prev" and "next". I am passing from other function to function that is coded in class where is  `JTable`. Problem is that I fill arrays which contains data for table but table won't update/refresh it. Here is my code. Thanks advance.

**BIG EDIT** Old code was removed. I added new codes that will help you guys/girls to understand problem that I have. Hope that this will help. Regards.

First here is class that show gui:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Glavni {
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                gui Scanner = new gui();
                Scanner.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Second here is class that pass String to gui class that contains jtable

```
public class passDatatoTable {
public void passData(){
    String str1,str2,str3,str4;
    gui SendStringsToGUI = new gui();
    for (int i =0;i<=10;i++){
            str1="Column 1 of row: "+i;
            str2="Column 2 of row: "+i;
            str3="Column 3 of row: "+i;
            str4="Column 4 of row: "+i;
            SendStringsToGUI.WriteMonitorData(str1, str2, str3, str4);

    }
  }
}
```

Next here is declaration of gui (contructor):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 String[][] data = new String[100][4];

 String[] columnNames = new String[]{
         "IP", "PC_NAME", "ttl", "db"
 };
 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);


    JTable table =  new JTable(model);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    int i=0;
public void WriteMonitorData (String IP, String PC_NAME, String ttl, String gw)
{
    System.out.println(IP);//just for testing (check if data was passed)
    model.setValueAt(IP, i, 0);
    model.setValueAt(PC_NAME, i, 1);
    model.setValueAt(ttl, i, 2);
    model.setValueAt(gw, i, 3);

    i++;
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    table.repaint();
    scrollPane.repaint();

}   
gui(){

JButton addData= new JButton("Add Data");
JButton next = new JButton("next");
JButton prev = new JButton("prev");
addData.addActionListener(this);
next.addActionListener(this);
prev.addActionListener(this);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add(addData);
buttonPanel.add(prev);
buttonPanel.add(next);
panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
panel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane().add(panel);
}
```

Here is actionListeners:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if ("Add Data".equals(e.getActionCommand())){

        passDatatoTable passSomeData = new passDatatoTable();
        passSomeData.passData();
              }
 if ("next".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
         Rectangle rect = scrollPane.getVisibleRect();
         JScrollBar  bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
         int blockIncr = scrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect().height;
             bar.setValue(bar.getValue() + blockIncr);
             scrollPane.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
     }
     if ("prev".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
         Rectangle rect = scrollPane.getVisibleRect();
         JScrollBar  bar = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
         int blockIncr = scrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect().height;
             bar.setValue(bar.getValue() - blockIncr);
             scrollPane.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
     }

  }
```

Comment: a) Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them. b) Never-ever call any of the fireXX methods outside of the model (the model _must_ handle that itself) c) never-ever call repaint (that's not needed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first snippet shows this:

`JTable table =  new JTable(model);`

but your `gui()` constructor shows:

`JTable table =  new JTable(data, columnNames);`

You initiate the table twice. Once using the `TableModel` ([`JTable(TableModel tm)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28javax.swing.table.TableModel%29)) the next using [`JTable(int rows,int cols)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#JTable%28int,%20int%29) this is not good, initiate the `JTable` once in the constructor:

```
gui() {
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
JTable table =  new JTable(model);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

JButton next = new JButton("next");
JButton prev = new JButton("prev");
next.addActionListener(this);
prev.addActionListener(this);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.add(prev);
buttonPanel.add(next);
panel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
panel.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
panel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
getContentPane().add(panel);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example that has a thread which will start 2.5 secinds after the UI is visible and change a value of the `JTable`:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().createAndShowUI();
            }
        });

    }

    private void createAndShowUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        initComponents(frame);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } 
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                       model.setValueAt("hello", 0, 0);
                     }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
    static DefaultTableModel model;

    private void initComponents(JFrame frame) {

        String data[][] = {
            {"1", "2", "3"},
            {"4", "5", "6"},
            {"7", "8", "9"},
            {"10", "11", "12"}
        };

        String col[] = {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3"};

        model = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);
        JTable table = new JTable(model);

        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I removed JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames); from constructor and it's still won't to refresh/update.

Comment: @ZhiZha please see my update. all works fine. You might want to create a short [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Thanks for your code. As I can see you are not passing from other class that updates table. Problem is that when you storing new data into array, that data will never update. That's my problem .... As I scan see you create Arrays of "data" with some data in it. My code works when you declare data in gui class. problem is that when you are add new data to array "data". That data might show on table... For me it's not showing...

Comment: I cannot see how your code demonstrates any of that (passing between classes and arrays of data that are set to the table after being set visible) I'd strongly suggest posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: You make the same mistake here as in your previous code snippet. You update Swing components on another thread then the EDT (by changing the table model in the runnable). Please adjust this

Comment: @Robin I got no idea how change the model on EDT from another thread

Comment: Either you use `SwingUtilities` (which you used already in your `main` method btw so you should be familiar with it - unless you simply have copy-pasted that code from somewhere without knowing what it means), or you ditch that `Thread` and replace it by a `javax.swing.Timer` which is designed to perform operations on the EDT at fixed intervals

Comment: @Robin ahhh thank you so much now its clear what Ive been doing wrong. And no all my code :). +1 to your answer teacher

Comment: I updated code. Please take a look now at code. Simply you can see what's going on. Still data in table doesn't refresh/update....

Comment: Thank @David Kroukamp for help. I updated code as you suggest. Please take a look now. Regards

Comment: And now you are sleeping on the EDT, which basically makes your UI unresponsive. My suggestion for the `SwingUtilities` call was not for the whole `Runnable`, just for the update-the-model part. I strongly suggest you read the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: @Robin maybe we are looking into this too much the sleep was to simulate loading of data and then changing of data after the frame is visible but I updated regardless

Comment: I know for what the sleep was meant. But simulating data loading, or actual data loading should not happen on the EDT. And for a post with a high number of upvotes (high means relative to other Swing related questions), the answer should not violate basic Swing threading rules imo. Now that it is corrected, I can remove my down vote

Comment: I tried with second constructor and still no luck. New constructor just replaced function WriteMonitorData(). Basicly new constructor does same thing like function WriteMonitorData(). I changed code for a bit and still no luck :( .

Comment: -1 for firing events on behalf of the model - that's the **exclusive** reponsibility of the model itself

Comment: @kleopatra ah I think I've learned more in these few comments then at school :) I will update code when near my PC.

Comment: being a bit stubborn: please remove the offending line instead of merely commenting it :-)

Comment: @kleopatra LOL a bit?!?!?!? :P Thank you for the help to get my code up to standard to all

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand from the comments and the question, you have first created a `DefaultTableModel` by passing the data as arrays in the constructor

```
String[][] data = new String[100][4];
String[] columnNames = new String[]{
     "IP", "PC_NAME", "ttl", "db"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,columnNames);
```

and you try to modify the table afterwards by adjusting those arrays. That will never ever have any effect, as the `DefaultTableModel` does not use those arrays. This can be seen in the source code of that class

```
public DefaultTableModel(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames) {
    setDataVector(data, columnNames);
}
```

which in the end comes down to

```
protected static Vector convertToVector(Object[][] anArray) {
    if (anArray == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Vector<Vector> v = new Vector<Vector>(anArray.length);
    for (Object[] o : anArray) {
        v.addElement(convertToVector(o));
    }
    return v;
}
```

So all the elements of the array are copied into an internal `Vector` and the array is no longer used.

Solution: do not update the arrays but update the `DefaultTableModel`. That class provides all the API you need to add/remove data to/from it.

Comment: Thanks Robin. I will try to implement your advice and code. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hi @Robin. Again thanks for help. Take a look at code that I updated. There's a whole code that's used. You can simply copy/paste it in eclipse... As you can see I am not using arrays anymore. I am using DefaultTableModel function setValueAt() which is used for adding new values to model. Still no data is showed...

Comment: @ZhiZha your `passDatatoTable` class still creates a new UI (`gui SendStringsToGUI = new gui();`) instead of updating the existing one

Comment: Thanks @Robin for update. So tell me how can I pass data correctly? I am thinking to create extra constructor with String as pass variable and from there it will update table and it won't create new GUI. I will try to code it and post back results.

Comment: I tried to use it with other constructor and still is not working. Does someone know good tutorial about this ? I am dealing with this for 2 days and still no luck...